# Bypass "Finish setup" screen after iOS Update with devices in kiosk mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, microsoft, mdm

We've about 300 devices (+ 300 employee coperate iphones) enrolled as media entertainment tablets. After the iOS 12.3 has been released, every devices installed that update. That's fine so far, but not what has to follow:

Since they're in kiosk mode, they stay black and can't be turned on! 
**1. Disable kiosk mode on all 600 devices**

Removal of kiosk mode will only become active, if the device reboots. We need to do this simultaneously on all, because iOS 12.3 info will only be shown in Microsoft Intune, after the manual confirmation of "Finish setup". All this, while at least 100 patients are watching live TV or Radio! 
**2. Reboot all 600 devices**

Since there is no feature for a "silent iOS Update" in entreprises, like us, we need to manually confirm that update on every of our 600 devices! 
**3. Manually confirm the update on all 600 devices**

As soon as we finished all previous steps we need to reactivate the kiosk mode and get back to 1. since 12.4 should be out if we're ready!!
**4. Enable kiosk mode on all 600 devices**

This was iOS update 12.2 > 12.3. How to handle iOS updates in a situation like ours?

Comment: Have you considered just setting them to not update? I'd be nervous about automatic updates anyway for single-purpose devices used on a large scale—what if the update breaks something? Particularly since downgrades are impossible on iOS.

Comment: There is no way to do that, since Apples' iOS MDM tools only allow you to postpone updates by a maximum of 90 days. You can't disable updates completely.

Comment: Yes, but there are other ways to do it, like blocking Apple's update server.